# how to code in java for bigquery API

Tags: java, eclipse, google-bigquery

I'm trying to learn to use bigquery API to get data from google database and import it to another sql database. I'm using eclipse java what application project should I set up? what plugin should I install?anyone has experience with this?

I'm more of a C# person,I used windows app form before, dont know how to do that in java. can anyone give some advise? Thanks!

To be more specific,I simply want to create an ETL to get bigquery data to our datawarehosue,it doesn't have to be a UI,i just need it to run on the backend. I install google plugin4.3
[image]

Which project is the easiest for me to use? Any successful code to get data from bigquery servlet to somewhere else?
I don't know how to plug the code in from:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart
Any instruction will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for more of a general Eclipse tutorial than something BigQuery specific.  You'd nominally create a "Java Project" to run simple Java code, but you'll need to set up the project to include your dependencies and so forth.

You may want to check these tutorials out : http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/totalbeginner.html

Alternately, you could Google for "eclipse tutorial" or "eclipse quickstart".